# avoid permission denied spam when using find-command

Tags: bash, find

I often try to find files with following syntax:

```
find . -name "filetofind"
```

However it usually results as many rows or error reporting (Permission denied) about folders where permission is denied. Is there any other way to avoid this spam than using sudo or advanced grepping from error-output?

Comment: Also related: [Ubuntu grep, find etc: "Permission denied" and "No such file or directory" output - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/382333/ubuntu-grep-find-etc-permission-denied-and-no-such-file-or-directory-outpu)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/54964

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name "filetofind" 2>/dev/null
```

This will redirect `stderr` output stream, which is used to report all errors, including "Access denied" one, to null device.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm :) I suppose there is no easy way to make it default option without creating an alias doing the same.

Comment: No, this is by design of the shell.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the `-perm` and `-prune` predicates to avoid descending into unreadable directories (see also [How do I remove "permission denied" printout statements from the find program? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-printout-statements-from-the-find-program/121020#121020)):

```
find . -type d ! -perm -g+r,u+r,o+r -prune -o -name "filetofind" -print
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see other errors and you don't have files named "permission denied" then this will work "better".

```
find . -name "filetofind" 2>&1 | grep -v 'permission denied'
```

Redirecting the output to grep with the inversion option.