# Ubuntu grep, find etc: "Permission denied" and "No such file or directory" output

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, find, grep

When I use `grep` or `find`, I always get annoyed by the "Permission denied" and "No such file or directory" notices, something like this:

```
johndoe@johndoe-desktop:/$ grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ | grep -v .svn
grep: ./lib/ufw/user6.rules: Permission denied
grep: ./lib/ufw/user.rules: Permission denied
grep: ./lib/init/rw/udev/watch/27: No such file or directory
grep: ./lib/init/rw/udev/watch/26: No such file or directory
grep: ./lib/init/rw/udev/watch/25: No such file or directory
```

How can I avoid them and make it so I only see relevant data, i.e. something that I'm really looking for?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/54964

Answer (score 29, accepted):

with grep you could specifiy the -s flag which does pretty much what @ortang said

> **-s, --no-messages**
>                 Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.  Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did
>   not conform to POSIX, because it  lacked  -q  and  its  -s  option
>                 behaved like GNU grep's -q option.  USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep.  Portable shell
>   scripts should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and
>                 error output to /dev/null instead.

with find as far as I know @ortangs answer is the best. 
something like

`find / -name "myfile" -type f -print 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 6):

Try redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

```
johndoe@johndoe-desktop:/$ grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ 2> /dev/null | grep -v .svn
```

Answer (score 5):

Redirecting the `strerr` to **`/dev/null`** (a.k.a **`black hole`**) is a good way of suppressing permission denied errors.

However, do note that this wound not only suppress `permission denied` messages but **ALL** error messages.

If you do wish to retain error messages other than `permission denied` then you can do something like this -

```
grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ 2>&1 | grep -v 'permission denied' > error.log
```

If you don't wish to retain those then the following would be just fine -

```
grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ 2> /dev/null | grep -v .svn
```

Comment: You cannot grep something that has been already redirected to /dev/null.

Comment: @choroba Have corrected the answer. Meant to write `2>&1` instead of `2> /dev/null` for first suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you have to redirect `stderr` to `stout` first.

Answer (score 3):

```
johndoe@johndoe-desktop:/$ sudo grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ | grep -v .svn
```

Use the `sudo` command to elevate the command to have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Using "|&" before the grep -v will deal with it, e.g.

```
grep -rnP 'YII_CORE_PATH' ./ | grep -v .svn |& grep -v 'permission denied'
```